# Total size of serialized results of tasks is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Good day.

I am running a development code for parsing some log files. My code will run smoothly if I tried to parse less files. But as I increase the number of log files I need to parse, it will return different errors such as `too many open files` and `Total size of serialized results of tasks is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize`.

I tried to increase the `spark.driver.maxResultSize` but the error still persists.

Can you give me any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

[image: Sample Error]

Comment: In my case, I increased maxResultSize to more than 1 gb than required and issue was solved. Your size of tasks is 5 gb. Can you try giving 6 gb once?

Comment: Please show the code...

Answer (score 17):

`Total size of serialized results of tasks is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize` means when a executor is trying to send its result to driver, it exceeds `spark.driver.maxResultSize`. Possible solution is as mentioned above by @mayank agrawal to keep on increasing it till you get it to work (not a recommended solution if an executor is trying to send too much data ).

I would suggest looking into your code and see if the data is skewed that is making one of the executor to do most of the work resulting in a lot of data in/out. If data is skewed you could try `repartitioning` it.

for too many open files issues , possible cause is Spark might be creating a number of intermediate files before shuffle. could happen if too many cores being used in executor/high parallelism or unique keys (possible cause in your case - huge number of input files). One solution to look into is consolidating the huge number of intermediate files through this flag : `--conf spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true` (when you do `spark-submit`)

One more thing to check is this thread (if that something similar to your use case): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12837

Comment: `spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles` will only help if you override the default to use `HashShuffleManager` instead of the default `HashShuffleManager` enabled by default after Spark 1.2 ([which defaults to `spark.shuffle.manager=sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/configuration.html)), and I think does not even apply to Spark 2.x