# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, amazon-emr

While executing my spark job getting below error. It is processing around 10 million records.  i'm executing on aws emr 5 node cluster. I'm comparing 2 files here. Each file having 5 million records. And accessing these files from S3. My instance type is : m4.2xlarge

**Tried with below command:**

spark-submit test-script.py --driver-memory 2G --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 4G

**Error log:**
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o210.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 780 tasks (1031.6 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1753)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1741)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1740)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1740)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1974)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1923)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1912)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:682)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3253)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3192)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: There are many posts on this error: [Total size of serialized results of 16 tasks (1048.5 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996396/total-size-of-serialized-results-of-16-tasks-1048-5-mb-is-bigger-than-spark-dr) and [Total size of serialized results of tasks is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763214/total-size-of-serialized-results-of-tasks-is-bigger-than-spark-driver-maxresults), for example.

Comment: I had gone through them all those links, but still problem not resolved. Thats why new problem opened.  Any way thanks for your time on this. I'm also looking into this, in case of any update. i'll share.

Comment: Also i tried with 10 node EMR cluster. Still same problem.

Comment: I would advice you to try with 'r4.8xlarge' instances by passing EFS volume as more than 300 gigs and --driver-memory 16G --driver-cores 4 --executor-memory 12G