# Pyspark job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: memory, pyspark

I am trying to create PySpark dataframe by using the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
#spark.sql("use bocconi")
tableName = "dynamic_pricing.final"
inputDF = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM dynamic_pricing.final WHERE year = '2019' AND mercati_id = '6'""")
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.sql.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 9730 tasks (1024.1 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)
```

I had gone through those links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763214/total-size-of-serialized-results-of-tasks-is-bigger-than-spark-driver-maxresults) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996396/total-size-of-serialized-results-of-16-tasks-1048-5-mb-is-bigger-than-spark-dr), but still problem not resolved. Any ideas about how to solve this?
I tried also this:

```
# Create new config
conf = (SparkConf()
    .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize",  0))

# Create new context
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Total size of serialized results of 9730 tasks is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize` means you're sending too much at once for the driver to receive. Looking at your maxResultSize of 1024.0 MB (only 1GB), I would advise you to increase your maxResultSize. Try setting it at 0 so it's unlimited and check if you have an out of memory error.

Comment: please see the edit, I tried to change maxresultsize, no luck

Comment: Do you have a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError ? Otherwise try `conf = (SparkConf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize",  "0"))`, I think it expects a string argument.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the spark executor instance and executor core from 1 to 2 solved the issue for me:
spark_executor_cores = 2
spark_executor_instances = 2

Development Environment: Azure Synapse and Azure machine learning.