# Unable to Create Extract - Tableau and Spark SQL

Tags: extract, tableau-api, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to make extract information from Spark SQL. Following error message showing while creating extract.

> [Simba][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 906 tasks (4.0 GB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (4.0 GB)'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46763214/total-size-of-serialized-results-of-tasks-is-bigger-than-spark-driver-maxresults

Comment: Still need help?

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is just changing the setting in your execution context.

`spark.sql("set spark.driver.maxResultSize = 8G")`

Comment: So you aren’t allowed to modify the query or even add another query? If they are worried about security you can add string variable then and assign the string “set spark.driver.maxResultSize = 8G” and add the variable to your query. Maybe let the extract owner know that and they can modify the query.

Comment: Assuming Spark Thrift Server is used, you can only execute SQL statement, Big Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely convinced on Spark SQL Thrift Server, and a little awkward to distill all facts. Tableau uses the results collect'ed to the driver, how else can it get them with Spark?

However:

- Set spark.driver.maxResultSize 0 in relevant spark-thrift-sparkconf.conf file will mean no limit (except physicals limits on driver node).
- Set spark.driver.maxResultSize 8G or higher in relevant spark-thrift-sparkconf.conf file. Note not all memory on driver can be used.
- Or, use Impala Connection for Tableau assuming a Hive Impala source, then less such issues.

Also, number of concurrent users can be a problem. Hence, last point.

Interesting to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

spark.driver.maxResultSize 0

This is the setting you can put in your advanced cluster settings. This will solve your 4 GB issue.